# Find first parent that satisfies condition sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, recursion, parent-child, hierarchy, common-table-expression

So I'm faced with a bit of a difficult problem, at least for me.

Imagine I'm working with not-so-fictional hierarchy data that contains branches, regions, etc. I've got some code that consumes data from a stored procedure, but recently ran into a problem when a cycle appeared.

To give you a feel for what the data my procedure consumes looks like:

```
Branch 12K3 Parent 12K
Branch 12K2 Parent 12K
Branch 12K  Parent REGION AA123
....
```

My job is to create new nodes and assign the appropriate parent from the above data. Sort of like below.

```
CPX Node 1 Parent REGION AA456
CPX Node 2 Parent REGION SomeOtherRegion
CPX Node 3 Parent 12K2
CPX Node 4 Parent 12K
```

Notice I have two nodes that have parents which happen to be a Branch. This is not desired.

**Goal:** For any CPX node whose parent is a Branch, walk up the hierarchy until we find the **first** node which happens to be a Region.

So in this case my nodes should look like this

```
CPX Node 1 Parent REGION AA456
CPX Node 2 Parent REGION SomeOtherRegion
CPX Node 3 Parent AA123 -- previously 12K2
CPX Node 4 Parent AA123 -- previously 12K
```

I'm new at this whole recursive CTE thing in 2005, so I naively tried this:

```
;with cte as
(
    -- initialization -- don't worry, this just checks for a cycle condition
    select t1.SourceID, t1.SourceParentID
    from @someTable t1
    inner join @someTable t2
    on t1.SourceID = t2.SourceParentID
    and t2.SourceID = t1.SourceParentID

    union all

    -- recursive execution
    select p.SourceID, gp.SourceParentID
    from cte p
    inner join entities as gp with (nolock)
    on gp.SourceID = p.SourceParentID
)
select * from cte
```

This would work but the recursion never terminates. If someone with more experience than me could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it!

Output of my SQL:

[image: IMG1]

Comment: I don't have an sql-server handy just now but, briefly, you need the second select statement to eventually select no results in order to terminate the expression. As it presently stands if each join to `entities` always succeeds then the recursion will never end. Try adding a where clause to the second query that checks that `gp` is not a REGION. If I were you I would then `row_number` the results and select the top row where the record is a region, ordered by row asc.